# Calling a NSTimer method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I'm new to working with timers on the `iPhone` and would need some support.

I have a method as below that takes the time and update a `UILabel` in my `userinterface`. I also have an `NSTimer` that calls that method once a second (I only show hours and minutes). This works just fine, except for the first second the App is live (as I understand it takes one second before the `timer` calls the method).

I would like to call my method from `viewDidLoad`, but how can I supply the right arguments? Or is there a better way of doing this?

```
// Timer for updating time
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(updateTime:) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];   


-(void)updateTime: (NSTimer *) timer {

    currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *currentTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
    [dateFormatter release];

    timeLabel.text =  currentTimeString;
}
```

Appreciate anything that would point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method, you don't use the timer variable right? So, why just call `[self updateTime:nil]`. That should work

Comment: Yes you are right. Such a simple and neat solution. Tested and is working fine.

Thanks!

Seems to also be a solution with "fire" that you can trigger the timer event but I have not had the time to test it yet.

Answer (score 2):

One more option ... you can do:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(updateTime:) 
                               userInfo:nil  
                                repeats:NO];    

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(updateTime:) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats: YES];
```

Comment: Thanks Horace.

I think I will go for vodkhangs solution though.